# Word for blog / article / tutorial

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I'm building a site with two main categories.

One side is portfolio work, the other is written work.
Among the written work, there will be personal blogs, tutorials, more in-depth articles, etc. I'm looking for a short, preferably single-word name for all of my written work.

I thought about using 'writings', but it feels a bit like bad choice because it's so close to the verb to *write*. Does anyone have opinions on this option or suggestion for a single word?

Comment: Create a title, and then in smaller text below, describe the contents.  Something like "PixelSnader's Random House" or "PixelSnader's Deep Thoughts."

Comment: "Documents" or "Publications" ?

Comment: @user116032 No, this isn't supposed to be the title of my column or anything. It's more like a menu button (e.g. this site has Questions | Tags | Users | Badges | Unanswered | Ask question) so conciseness is important.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using "[**post**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/post)" which means:

> A piece of writing, image, or other item of content **published online**,
>   typically on a blog or social media website: '*in a recent post, he cautioned investors to be wary of these predictions*'.

It is better than "[writings](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/writing)" as they include

> books, stories, or other written works.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: 'Posts' is too generic for my liking. Firstly because all portfolio pieces will also be posts; some just 1 image, some several + text explanation. And secondly because Wordpress uses the term, which can cause confusion. Like you said, a post is pretty much anything published online, and I want some more specificity.

Comment: @PixelSnader I see. I edited your post with a "single-word-request" tag which is popular here. Let's wait for other users' answers. I will delete my post.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions. The first is **essays**. NOAD defines *essay* as

> **essay** (*n.*)
>   a short piece of writing on a particular subject

The second would be **musings**. Again, from NOAD:

> **musing** (*n.*)
>    <sup>(usu. **musings**)</sup>
>   a period of reflection or thought

---

By itself, *musings* wouldn't necessarily imply written works – not in the same way *essays* would. However, in the context of a website, the word "musings" would imply *written* musings, I think. If most of these articles had a personal touch, such a heading could give your website a more "homey" feel.

Comment: We all have words we dislike.  I can't explain why I feel this way, but when I see "musings" I think of somebody pompous who's about to show us all how smart he is.  Proactive is another one.  If it weren't so academic "letters" would work. Good luck with you site.

Comment: @user116032 - Yup, that's why this was as much a suggestion as it was an answer. I may not share your same negativity toward _musings_, but I can see where you're coming from.